# Apache Spark: read files and zip the lines

Tags: apache-spark

Say, I have two text files -- in HDFS or a local filesystem. I know that each contains exactly `N` lines `l1_1`, `l1_2`, ...., `l2_1`, `l2_2`,... . Lengths of the lines can vary significantly and I don't know them in advance. I read the files:

```
val textFile1 = sc.textFile("file1.txt")
val textFile2 = sc.textFile("file2.txt")
```

And now I zip them:

```
val zipped = textFile1 zip textFile2
```

Does Spark guarantees that the lines will be zipped in a sequential order, i.e. `l1_1` with `l2_1`, `l1_2` with `l2_2`, etc? If not, what should I do to ensure this?

Comment: Not that I mind your having followup questions, but if you significantly elaborate the content of your question, perhaps you would consider opening another question on this website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does:

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List.tabulate(10)((x) => x))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[3] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> val rdd3 = rdd1 zip rdd2
rdd3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = ZippedPartitionsRDD2[4] at zip at <console>:26

scala> rdd3.take(10)
res2: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((0,a), (1,b), (2,c), (3,d), (4,e), (5,f), (6,g), (7,h), (8,i), (9,j))
```

`textFile` gives you an `RDD` with one `String` element per line, irrespective of the size of the lines, and even if you read from HDFS. The semantics of `zip` are constant and always respect the interleaving of lines, if only because `zip` returns an `RDD` of pairs of lines. Note however that `zip` only works with `RDD`s that have the same number of elements per partition (and, as a consequence, that must also mean that your `RDD`s contain the same number of lines).

Consider `repartition` if you're not happy with the default partitioning of `textFile`. Look at `toDebugString` or [this](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/performance_optimization/how_many_partitions_does_an_rdd_have.html) to inspect the content of your `RDD`s.

Comment: Well, thanks, but I know that in simple cases this is true. The question is, is it  _always_  true? What if we read files from HDFS? What if files are partitioned among several different nodes? What if one file has very short lines, and another very long -- maybe rdds of them will have different number of partitions and zip will not work at all? I think we need to understand the internals of `sc.textFile` to answer these questions.